# cv2.resize changes color mode of my image

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing, imshow, imread

I want to resize an image but it turns blue when I use the method.

---

My venv has:
Python 3.9
opencv-python==4.5.5.64

I'm working on a .ipynb file through Pycharm.

Have this cell after imports:

```
sns.set_theme(style='whitegrid',
              rc={'figure.figsize': (20, 10),
                  'axes.grid' : False})
```

---

Here is my code:

In 1

```
img = cv2.imread('../sample_img/secret/sample_img_secret.jpeg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img);
```

Out 1

[image]
In 2

```
img = cv2.imread('../sample_img/secret/sample_img_secret.jpeg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
plt.imshow(img);
```

Out 2

[image]

---

I can't figure what's happening even diving in the docs and SO. This used to work on an earlier notebook.

Thx in advance!!

Comment: Why are you converting from BGR to RGB?  OpenCV uses BGR color orientation and converts the input RGB into BGR automatically to preserve the color.  By your changing back to RGB, you are swapping Blue and Red channels and displaying them out of order.

Comment: @frm42. May I ask. Cannot convert from opencv to matplotlib to resizing.

Comment: @fmw42 as screens work with RGB I change the color mode to display the image with correct colors (as shown in first image). My problem is that when I apply the resize method this color mode change seems to have no effect.

Comment: Try cv2.imshow() to view your image. Is your input JPG RGB or CMYK?

Comment: Thx for your answer @fmw42 but as far as I know plt.imshow() uses by default cmap=None and that's why in the first image I get correct colors. Am I wrong?
  

Edit: the raw image is JPEG RGB

Comment: Try cv2.imshow() on both images (in BGR mode) and see if you still have color change. (plt.imshow() uses a color map for grayscale image and no color map for color image, as far as I know). I prefer cv2.imshow() as it does not use any colormaps by default.

Comment: Just posted the solution.. You won't believe it.. Thx for your help and your insistence @fmw42

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer when opening the notebook from VSCode. It's just a PyCharm setting which was creating the mess.

In case you are in the same situation just disable:

Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Jupyter | Invert image outputs for dark themes

Got the answer from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54138

[Settings location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbA86.png)